# CPU usage increase when changing number of cores of the VM lively

Tags: virtualization, cpu, kvm-virtualization, cpu-load

I am working on increasing the number of virtual cores of the KVM virtual machines lively using libvirt. I created a virtual machine with 2 cores. Here are the initial core settings.

```
virsh vcpucount 2
maximum      config        32
maximum      live          32
current      config         2
current      live           2
```

I also attach initial CPU usage output using htop.
[image: Output of CPU usage initially]

After that, I increase the number of cores to 4 using the following command

```
virsh setvcpus 2 4 --live
```

I check the current core configuration of the VM

```
virsh vcpucount 2
maximum      config        32
maximum      live          32
current      config         2
current      live           4
```

It looks like I was able to increase the number of cores from 2 to 4. However, I realize weirdness in terms of CPU usage. After I allocated 2 more cores, I observed the following CPU usage.
[image: Output of CPU usage after adding new cores]
The problem here is that added two cores are at the 100% level. When I back to 2 cores again, CPU usage returns to normal.

Do you know why it happens?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? I can not try your command on my system because my vCPUs are not hotpluggable (according to the error I get when I try).

Comment: I should have mentioned my system details. Here are details: OS 
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, virsh version 4.0.0, and libvirtd version 4.0.0. What error did you get?

Comment: I got this: `error: unsupported configuration: failed to find appropriate hotpluggable vcpus to reach the desired target vcpu count`

Comment: I do not know your VM configuration file but mine has the following line about vcpu. <vcpu placement='static' cpuset='0-31' current='2'>32</vcpu> By having this, I can increase number of CPU from 2 to till 32.

Comment: My test server is Ubuntu 20.04.4. Your vcpu configuration works fine on it, no great increase in host CPU use when changing from 2 to 4 CPUs.

Comment: What version of libvirt you have?

Comment: 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16

Comment: Well, consumed CPU is burned somewhere - I assume below your screenshots you see that from the hosts POV qemu is consuming the time, otherwise you'd have been suspicious already :-) You want to check if it is a vcpu thread or anything else maybe `pidstat -p $(pgrep -f 'name guest=<yourguestname>') -T ALL -tr 5`. Once you know it is "in the guest" consider runining htop in there or even go for `perf top` to know even better (needs some prereq installs). Update the case where your CPU is burned to get suggestions how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was fixed after I upgraded Ubuntu OS version. I was using version `18.04.4 LTS`. In addition, the kernel version was `4.15.0-153-generic`. After I upgraded the OS to `20.04.4 LTS (kernel version: 5.4.0-121-generic)`, it was fixed. The problem must have about KVM kernel module version.

Comment: Thank you for reporting back your findings. Most don't.